# How to access arraylist from an other void then it is generated in in Java?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to access an arraylist from another void then it is generated in in Java?
(I'm making an android app, i did cut down the code massively)

```
package com.example.example;

import ...;

public class Example {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
//android things here...
        ArrayList<String> questionid = new ArrayList<String>();
        questionid.add("1");
        questionid.add("2");
        questionid.add("3");
        questionid.add("4");
        questionid.add("5");
        questionid.add("6");
        questionid.add("7");
        questionid.add("8");
        questionid.add("9");
        questionid.add("10");
        Collections.shuffle(questionid, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
}

    private void newQuestion() {
        questionid.get(0); //<-- It doesn't find the arraylist questionid
        }
    }

    private void setNewQuestion() {
        TextView questionnumberlabel;
        questionnumberlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionnumber);
        if (questionnumberlabel.getText().equals("1")) {

        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to make the arraylist accessible everywhere in the class? Again, i'm developing an app for android, so i did cut down the code a bit.

Comment: What to you mean by "an other void"? Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: If you don't have time to write a decent question, you shouldn't post a question at all. Wait until you *have* got time, then read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints (It sounds like you should have an instance variable where you've currently got a local variable, but that's really just a guess at the moment...)

Comment: Answered - but it's important to use appropriate terminology. There's no such thing as "other void" - it sounds like you really mean "another method"... the `void` part just happens to be the return type of the two methods you've created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've currently declared `questionid` as a *local variable* in the `onCreate` method. That variable only exists for the duration of that method call. You want an *instance* variable - i.e. something which is part of the state of the object, and which is available within all methods.

```
public class Example {
    private ArrayList<String> questionid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        questionid = new ArrayList<String>();
        questionid.add("1");
        ...
    }

    private void newQuestion() {
        String firstQuestion = questionid.get(0);
        ...
    }
}
```